# PHP code in body tags

Tags: php, html, css

I tried putting some php in the body tag to change the background color of the page based on what value was passed from the first page but it's not working.

Can I do this? (Add php code inside body tag)

If not, what would be the easiest way to change the background color of the page based on the value passed from the first page

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    <meta charset=utf-8>
<title></title>
</head>
    <body <?php
    $teamvar = $_POST['team_id'];
    if($teamvar == 1){
        $teamvar = "Celtics";
        echo "style='background-color: green;'>"
    } else {
        echo "style='background-color: yellow;'>"; }
            ?> 
        <div id=content> 
        <p>
        Test
        </p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Close your body tag!

Comment: @Rizier123: ...it is closed. Not in a very readable way though.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen No i mean the first body tag has no `>`

Comment: You should also put quotes for `<div id=content>`.

Comment: @Rizier123: And what I meant by "not very readable" is that it's being closed by one of his `echo`s. Read the code more carefully!

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Okay now i know what you meant with "not very readable"! Sry my bad saw it

Comment: So what exactly does "not working" mean here? What actually happens? What does the *rendered* output look like?

Comment: The page just comes back totally blank, I open the source and there's literally nothing there. I'm lost

Comment: Have you checked your server logs for errors? A blank page or 500 error usually means there's an error in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You missed a semi-colon `;` at the end of `echo "style='background-color: green;'>"`

Change it to:

```
echo "style='background-color: green;'>";
```

and it will work.

You should also put quotes for `<div id=content>`

```
<div id="content">
```

which is just good form.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks like it should work to me. Are you sure you're posting the correct value? Try printing out the posted value on the page to see. Or just `var_dump($_POST);`.

However as it is your code isn't very readable. It's best not to intermingle HTML and logic. I'd do something like this:

```
<?php
    $teamid = $_POST["team_id"];
    if ($teamid == "1"){
        $color = "green";
    } else {
        $color = "yellow";
    }
?>
...
<body style="background-color: <?= $color %>;">
```

Comment: No matter what I do it comes back with a blank page, it seems to not like the code in the body tage idk why

Comment: @JakeParis: I think they're much more readable for just printing a value.

Comment: Perhaps, but not every server supports them, so it makes your code less portable.

Comment: @JakeParis: I'm sure everybody who is running PHP less than 5.4 (a.k.a. PHP "almost three years ago") where <?= ?> can be turned off can make the necessary changes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    <meta charset=utf-8>
<title></title>
</head>

<?php
  $body_style = "";
  $teamvar = $_POST['team_id'];
  if($teamvar == 1){
      $teamvar = "Celtics";
      $body_style ="style='background-color: green;'>";
  } else {
      $body_style = "style='background-color: yellow;'>"; 
  }       
 ?>
    <body <?php echo $body_style; ?> >

        <div id="content"> 
        <p>
        Test
        </p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: still just brings back a blank page

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add ; you can try now.

Comment: Where am I missing a ;?

Comment: First $body_style, $body_style ="style='background-color: green;'>"

Comment: You should turn on error reporting error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 1):

Your code **isn't** wrong, but you can use it in a better way, for example.

```
<html>
<head>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    <meta charset=utf-8>     
    <title></title>   
</head>   

<?php
if (isset($_POST['team_id']) {
    if($_POST['team_id'] == 1)
        $variable = "style='background-color: green;'>";
    else
        $variable = "style='background-color: yellow;'>";
} else 
    $variable = "style='background-color: yellow;'>";
?>     
    <body <?php echo $variable;?>> 
        <div id=content> 
            <p>
                Test
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, this code is more aesthetic than yours.

Comment: Actually, the only thing that was missing in the OP's code was a semi-colon; a syntax error which you also made `$variable = "style='background-color: green;'>"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is you working code

```
 <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    <meta charset=utf-8>
<title></title>
</head>
    <body <?php

    $teamvar = $_POST['team_id'];
    if($teamvar == 1){{
        $teamvar = "Celtics";
        echo "style='background-color: green;'>";
    } else {
        echo "style='background-color: yellow;'>"; }
            ?> 
        <div id=content>
        <p>
        Test
        </p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

you can test it :)

Comment: WRONG! You changed the condition!

Comment: because i dont have post value its a dummy value if not then make a fiddle form ur self to us !

Comment: are u mad or what i didnot

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks bad! But this should work:

(BTW: You forgot a `;` in your code)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <?php

        //Test
        $_POST['team_id'] = 1;
        $teamvar = $_POST['team_id'];

        if($teamvar == 1) {
            $teamvar = "Celtics";
            echo "<body style='background-color: green;'>";
        } else {
            echo "<body style='background-color: yellow;'>";
        }

    ?> 

        <div id="content"> 
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Also i would recommend you to turn on error reporting with this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is this the same code the OP has?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you explained what you fixed.